# Why does Ben and Jerry's boycott of the occupied territories further BDS's cause?

Tags: israel, palestine

Ben and Jerry's is an ice cream company known for taking controversial stances. It recently announced that it will stop selling ice cream in Israeli occupied areas like Palestine.

This seems very bizarre. There is a group called Boycott Divestment and Sanctions which seems to be doing the opposite and it gets the same sort of response. Because of this I thought if anything they would celebrate this. *Why was this move seen as anti Israeli?*

Comment: Their boycott is part of the BDS movement, right? It's not the opposite.

Comment: Explain. Isn't BDS about boycotting Israel not Palestine?

Comment: I guess I can try to explain the reasoning in an answer.  Something like: why does B&J's boycott of the occupied territories further BDS's cause?

Comment: @NumberFile They are not boycotting Palestine. They are boycotting the parts of Palestine that is occupied by Israelis and thus have had Palestinians thrown out of. They are boycotting Israelis in Palestine. The reality is in Palestine that actually contains Palestinians it is already difficult to get anything like Ben & Jerry's ice cream because of the general embargo by the Israeli government

Comment: @slebetman Except there is no embargo of food into Gaza/West Bank.  All that's blockaded are things with military use.

Comment: @slebetman there's certainly ice cream in Palestine, including the Palestinian-controlled A zone

Comment: @NumberFile Split-definition there. Land isn't boycotted. Companies are. When Israel violates international law and builds illegal settlements in Palestine the Israeli companies are boycotted that operate there, precisely because they're there to the benefit of the colonizer and not the Palestinians. The land is however not boycotted. If a Palestinian owned it and it employed Palestinians it would certainly not be a target of BDS.

Comment: As a side note, Ben & Jerry's can't prevent any supermarket owner from buying a ton of their ice cream inside Israel, and sell it in the West Bank.

Answer (score 14):

So Ben & Jerry's wrote a [brief statement about this](https://www.benjerry.com/about-us/media-center/palestine-statement) (this isn't the full statement, just a relevant part):

> We believe it is inconsistent with our values for Ben & Jerry’s ice cream to be sold in the Occupied Palestinian Territory (OPT). We also hear and recognize the concerns shared with us by our fans and trusted partners.

The [Boycott, Divestment and Sanctions (BDS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boycott,_Divestment_and_Sanctions) is about protesting against Israel's occupation of [certain territories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli-occupied_territories) (corresponding to the OPT mentioned in Ben & Jerry's statement above).

The reasoning for this boycott is simple. As reasoned from the BDS perspective, having access to Ben & Jerry's ice cream is a privilege which those in the occupied territories are not entitled to because BDS disagrees with the occupation. If many companies boycott the occupied territories then it is less enjoyable to live there.

The boycott will also affect Palestinians living in those occupied territories, but that's part of the collective punishment nature of boycotts (and sanctions). See also [this answer by Rivers McForge](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/66561) on Google's restricting access to some of its services as a response to the internal conflict in Myanmar:

> Sanctions are a little like collective punishment in school, e.g. the teacher finds out that cheating took place on a test, so they dock everyone's grade regardless of culpability, in order that the students who cheated will face pressure from other students not to do so in the future. The collateral damage is the point.

In this case the collateral damage is probably not intended, but a company cannot institute a more targeted boycot even if it wanted to.

Of course, a broader implementation of the boycott could include suspending the sale of their ice cream in Israel itself, but for some reason Ben & Jerry's have chosen not to take it that far.

Some more background from [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/jul/20/israel-pm-aggressive-action-ben-jerrys-ban-ice-cream-naftali-bennett-occupied-territories-unilever):

> BDS applauded Ben & Jerry’s decision as “a decisive step towards ending the company’s complicity in Israel’s occupation and violations of Palestinian rights”, but called on the company to do more.
>
> “We hope that Ben & Jerry’s has understood that, in harmony with its social justice commitments, there can be no business as usual with apartheid Israel,” it said.
>
> Several other international businesses and investors have pulled out of Israeli settlements or instigated secondary boycotts of companies involved in settlement-building in recent years. The highest-profile example was Airbnb, which in 2018 announced it would remove listings in West Bank settlements but eventually reneged on the decision.
>
> The EU has also applied consistent pressure, ruling in 2019 that member states must identify products made in Israeli settlements on their labels.

---

> Why was this move seen as anti Israeli?

Israel views that those occupied territories are just as much part of Israel as the rest of Israel or [that Israel at least has a credible claim to the land](https://www.jcpa.org/jl/vp470.htm). They see this boycott as giving in to the BDS movement, again from [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/jul/20/israel-pm-aggressive-action-ben-jerrys-ban-ice-cream-naftali-bennett-occupied-territories-unilever):

> Israel’s foreign ministry also condemned the decision as “a surrender to ongoing and aggressive pressure from extreme anti-Israel groups” and said the company was cooperating with “economic terrorism”.

And there's also a risk that more companies will follow Ben & Jerry's lead, which means that those living in the occupied territories may have less privileges (access to certain services or goods) than they do without these boycotts. Again from [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/jul/20/israel-pm-aggressive-action-ben-jerrys-ban-ice-cream-naftali-bennett-occupied-territories-unilever):

> A political source told Haaretz news organisation there were fears that other international companies might follow Ben & Jerry’s lead under pressure from the BDS movement – a Palestinian-led initiative advocating boycotts, divestment and sanctions against Israeli institutions and businesses, which many Israelis denounce as antisemitic.

Comment: I think part of the reasons they still sell in Israel is due to the fact that they manufacture it there. From what I read Israel is already threatening action over what they have done so far. https://www.forbes.com/sites/jemimamcevoy/2021/07/20/israel-warns-of-severe-consequences-legal-and-otherwise-after-ben--jerrys-settlement-ban/?sh=79c0cf7756d9

Comment: I think there is an important point to make here that could clarify the answer. As understand it, Ben and Jerry's has not stopped selling *in Palestine* but rather in *Israeli settlements in Palestine*, like AirBNB. BDS is not cheering for Palestinians being unable to buy ice cream (although that may well occur as an unintended side effect); they are pleased that it will not be sold to Israelis in territory that they consider to be part of Palestine.

Comment: @JoeW Yea, and I guess the current boycott, small as the impact may be economically (both from Israel and B&J's point of view), has already raised a lot of headlines.

Comment: @Obie2.0 included a parallel to sanctions, I guess that sort of address your point.

Comment: My impression is that they only stopped selling in the settlements. Is that incorrect? Did they sell ice cream in Palestine outside the settlements before, and now they have stopped doing so?

Comment: @Obie2.0 I am not sure if they currently or previously sold ice cream in Palestine. I think it's clear though that the current boycott is aimed at the occupied territories only.  It also doesn't make sense to stop selling in non-occupied Palestine if they want to support Palestine.

Comment: @JJJ - The thing is that some people use the term occupied Palestinian territories to refer the West Bank, Gaza Strip, and so forth.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Yea I'm not sure which territories are covered exactly. The Ben & Jerry's statement only refer to *'Occupied Palestinian Territory (OPT)'*.

Comment: I could imagine a situation in which Ben and Jerry's had only been selling in the settlements in the first place, which would neatly explain BDS's support of the decision (they may be willing to support sanctions on Israel that may indirectly affect the Palestinian economy, but it would be surprising for them to oppose *food* being sold directly to Palestinians) and why Ben and Jerry's used a broad term that suggests that they stopped selling in the whole country.

Comment: *for some reason Ben & Jerry's have chosen not to take it that far* - Actually, there have been reports that the Ben & Jerry's Board actually did want to take it that far, or at least *not* say "we'll still be in Israel" and that Unilever overruled Ben & Jerry's by specifically stating that they would figure out a way to continue selling in Israel.

Comment: > Israel views that those occupied territories are just as much part of Israel as the rest of Israel

I don't think Israel holds that view officially - if they did it would suggest that people born there were entitled to the same electoral and other rights as people born in Israel.

Comment: @bdsl yea it's a bit of a tricky statement, that's why I added the *or that Israel at least has a credible claim to the land*. I don't think the specific position is important for the question. Israel seems to feel it's enough of their business to be outraged.

Comment: I'd also note that the boycott is purely symbolical. BJ don't have the power to stop local store owners from purchasing a truckload of their ice cream in other Israeli cities and then selling it in, say, East Jerusalem.

Answer (score 9):

The idea behind this is that Israel's occupation of Palestine territories is illegal.

Ben & Jerry's has no trouble with Israel *inside its internationally recognized borders*, so they keep their commercial operations there.

But keeping their operations in the occupied territories would force them to follow Israel's laws<sup>1</sup> in a place they do not believe to rightfully belong to Israel<sup>2</sup>.

Ben & Jerry's could chose to avoid operations in all of Israel, but then:

- It could be claimed that it was an issue of antisemitism (they are not just against the occupation of Palestinian lands but against all of the state of Israel).
- It would take the focus away from considering the difference between the situation of both territories (Israel and occupied territories).

Such an action emphasizes that, for B&J's management, there is a difference between Israel and the occupied territories, i.e. *that the occupied territories are not Israel*. That statement, coming from a non-aligned source, is often more important than the economical effects themselves (I am pretty sure there are other local and/or international companies selling ice-cream there).

<sup>1</sup> Including paying taxes to Israel, or whatever restrictions Israel laws impose on Palestinian workers and consumers.

<sup>2</sup> If they believed that it belonged to Israel, they would not be making differences between the occupied territories and Israel "proper".

Comment: Maybe so, but does BDS actually oppose companies selling things in Palestine as whole (which is often what the term Occupied Palestinian Territories means), including food products? Or is it perhaps the case that Ben and Jerry's mainly (exclusively?) sold products in Israeli settlements? If this answer suggests that BDS supports companies not doing business in Palestine overall, and if that is correct, a reference could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to all other answers;

It seems like most of the participants in this discussion have just gotten the facts wrong.

Ben & Jerry's has a contract with an Israeli ice cream manufacturer which uses the entity name "Ben and Jerry's Israel". Under the contract, B&J Israel manufactures and sells ice cream in Israel using the Ben and Jerry's label.

Wishing to boycott Jews living in Judea and Samaria (the West Bank), Ben & Jerry's asked from B&J Israel to discontinue its sales in Judea and Samaria, but the later refused.

As a result, Ben And Jerry's may choose not to extend the contract which expires towards the end of 2022. If this will be the case, B&J Israel may be forced to discontinue the use of the "Ben And Jerry's" label.

That's all. Jews and Arabs living in Judea and Samaria will continue to enjoy ice cream, but they may become deprived of the B&J label (if they care).

Comment: Why the downvote? Is anything in my answer not correct?

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but are you sure that the only thing Ben and Jerry’s is licensing is their brand name? Wouldn’t the manufacturer have to change their licensed  recipe and flavors?

Comment: You might have been downvoted for using the politicized pro-settler term “Judea and Samaria” instead of the internationally accepted term “The West Bank”. That might make people assume you’re arguing in favor of Israeli annexation here. Whatever your views are, that’s irrelevant to the question, so I  recommend sticking with West Bank