# Why Google Ban Myanmar Effect Student

Tags: united-states, myanmar

How long it takes when Google Ban a country ?

Comment: Welcome to Politics! As it's written, this question seems to be about Google's policy rather than some government policy. This site deals mostly with governmental politics, not the policies of (large) companies.

Comment: Just a guess: probably as long as it takes for the Myanmar government to stop being a brutal dictatorship. When this happens, the [US will probably lift the sanctions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/66553/23571) and Google will stop the ban.